# Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'dart.core::int'

Tags: dart, flutter

I need help with an error I get while running a flutter project. I made a clone of

https://github.com/miketraverso/devfestapp.

After getting all the packages updated - I got the following error: Compiler message:

```
lib/views/scheduled_session_widget.dart:51:34: Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'dart.core::int'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '[]'.
mSessions[sessionIter['0'].toString()]; // ignore: undefined_operator
```

Could someone explain what I could do to solve this error ?

Comment: Try to upgrade your dart and flutter version to latest..

Comment: After upgrade I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sessions is collection of ints: `List<int> sessions;` in class TimeSlot, and later you have forEach on it so you can replace that code with:

```
 timeSlot.sessions.forEach((sessionIter) {
      Session session = mSessions[sessionIter.toString()];
      if (session != null) {
        Widget sessionCard = buildSessionCard(timeSlot, session);
        sessionCards.add(sessionCard);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I replaced and get no error now but while running it does not get data from the Firebase Real Time database.